# Make jQuery submenu expand parent AND Prevent repeating slideToggle effect

Tags: jquery, hover, slidetoggle, expand, repeat

I have put together a navigation bar which expands a submenu on hover. See my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aQBeZ/6/).

If you hover on the menu items, the submenu expands beyond the parent `<nav>` (which I have coloured blue). What I am after is for the blue `<nav>` element to expand with the child `<ul>`.

I don't know if I need a jQuery or css solution but everything I have tried so far has been in vain.

**AND**

If your mouse happens to quickly hover across the navigation, say from 'MENU 3' to 'MENU 1' then rest on a submenu item such as 'ONE A' (before it actually appears), the jQuery gets stuck in a repeating loop where each submenu opens and closes.

What needs to be changed to prevent this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add stop() after  $(this).find('ul')  this should help with animations.

```
$(document).ready(

function() {
    $('.menu li ul').hide();
    $('.menu li').hover(function(e) {
        $(this).find('ul').stop().slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

And the reason menu does not expand is that your ".menu li ul" is set to position absolute. When element has absolute position it is removed from the normal flow

Comment: Thanks @Ivan, this worked perfectly, exactly what I was after. Just a note to anyone else experiencing the same problem...this fix didn't work for me initially, it messed up the positioning of the submenu. It was only when I realised I was running an old version of jQuery(1.5) and updated it to latest that this solution worked.

Comment: ...and the positioning makes sense now you've said it. The only way around it that I can think of is setting a different class for each submenu with relative positioning for each. I'll give it a try unless there's a simpler way...

Answer (score 0):

It happens because the animations are queued and they continue to run unless you forcefully stop them.

The [JQuery's](http://jquery.com) [`stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) function would help you here.

`stop(clearQueue, jumpToEnd)`- Stops the currently-running animation on the matched elements.

```
$(this).find('ul').stop(true, true).slideToggle("slow");
```

Check the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aQBeZ/9/