# How to prevent repeating slideToggle effect on Dropdown menu?

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, slidetoggle

I have a navigation menu that expands a submenu on hover. My issue is that when I hover on the menu items, the submenu expands and then when i leave the mouse from the menu i get the slideToggle effect repeats and the submenu stops.

See my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ysNwg/).

to fix it I tried to add `.stop()` before `.slideToggle()` as explained here: [Make jQuery submenu expand parent AND Prevent repeating slideToggle effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11134876/make-jquery-submenu-expand-parent-and-prevent-repeating-slidetoggle-effect) but doesn't work.

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply restrict the `hover()`action to the `li`of `menu` class, otherwise the hover occurs on every subsequent li which is not what you intended.

```
    $("li.menu").on("hover", ...
```

See [update of your jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HighKickX/ysNwg/1/)

Answer (score 3):

change your 2nd line of javascripts code from

```
$("li").on("hover", function(e){
```

to this

```
$(".menu").on("hover", function(e){
```